# How to merge elements within the same list?

Tags: python

```
list = [['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

How could I generate following outcome?

```
list = [['1\r\na', '2\r\nb', '3\r\nc']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of @Psidom's answer but using string formatting:

```
lst = [['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

new_list = ["{}\r\n{}".format(a, b) for a, b in zip(*lst)]
```

Output:

```
['1\r\na', '2\r\nb', '3\r\nc']
```

Comment: Though both methods work, I rather prefer using string formatting. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

You can *zip* the list with `zip(*lst)` which zips all the sublists in the original list and then *join* each tuple with `\r\n`:

```
lst = [['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

['\r\n'.join(t) for t in zip(*lst)]
# ['1\r\na', '2\r\nb', '3\r\nc']
```